# 32/64-bit ReadProcessMemory issues

Tags: delphi, x86, 64-bit, readprocessmemory

I always used this code on x86 machines without problems:

```
PIDHandle:= OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or
                                          PROCESS_VM_READ, false, Struct.th32ProcessID);
if (PIDHandle <> 0)
 ScanMemory(PIDHandle, Struct.szExeFile);

procedure TForm1.ScanMemory(PIDHandle: THandle; const ProcessName: string);
var
  MemStart, ReceivedBytes: SIZE_T;
  MemInfo: MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
begin
  MemStart:= 0;
  while (VirtualQueryEx(PIDHandle, Pointer(MemStart), MemInfo, SizeOf(MemInfo)) <> 0) do
  begin
    if ((MemInfo.State = MEM_COMMIT) and (not (MemInfo.Protect = PAGE_GUARD)
    or (MemInfo.Protect = PAGE_NOACCESS)) and (MemInfo.Protect = PAGE_READWRITE)) then
    begin
      SetLength(Buff, MemInfo.RegionSize);
      if (ReadProcessMemory(PIDHandle, MemInfo.BaseAddress, Buff,
          MemInfo.RegionSize, ReceivedBytes)) then
        begin
          //do particular stuff with memory
        end; //if readprocessmemory
    end; //if mempages
    MemStart:= MemStart + MemInfo.RegionSize;
  end; 
end;
```

Now I compiled a x64 binary and it stops responding in some random processes, which I'm not sure if they are x86/x64...

Are there any known issue on running ReadProcessMemory from a x64 bin, into x86 processes?
Is really necessary to keep a x86 bin to read memory of other x86 processes and a x64 bin to read x64 processes? Or there are any workaround?

Comment: 64 bit process can operate on a 32 bit process. Why not do some debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `ReadProcessMemory()`, it is with `VirtualQueryEx()`.

The [MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366775.aspx) documentation says:

> To enable a debugger to debug a target that is running on a different architecture (32-bit versus 64-bit), use one of the explicit forms of this structure.
>
> ```cpp
> typedef struct _MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32 {
>     DWORD BaseAddress;
>     DWORD AllocationBase;
>     DWORD AllocationProtect;
>     DWORD RegionSize;
>     DWORD State;
>     DWORD Protect;
>     DWORD Type;
> } MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32, *PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32;
>
> typedef struct DECLSPEC_ALIGN(16) _MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64 {
>     ULONGLONG BaseAddress;
>     ULONGLONG AllocationBase;
>     DWORD     AllocationProtect;
>     DWORD     __alignment1;
>     ULONGLONG RegionSize;
>     DWORD     State;
>     DWORD     Protect;
>     DWORD     Type;
>     DWORD     __alignment2;
> } MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64, *PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64;
> ```

So, use `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32` when querying a 32bit process, and use `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64` when querying a 64bit process.  However, Delphi does not declare these record types, so you will have to do so manually in your code.

Delphi's declaration of `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` in the `Windows` unit is modeled after the old 32-bit version:

```cpp
typedef struct _MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION {
  PVOID  BaseAddress;
  PVOID  AllocationBase;
  DWORD  AllocationProtect;
  SIZE_T RegionSize;
  DWORD  State;
  DWORD  Protect;
  DWORD  Type;
} MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
```

```pascal
PMemoryBasicInformation = ^TMemoryBasicInformation;
_MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION = record
  BaseAddress : Pointer;
  AllocationBase : Pointer;
  AllocationProtect : DWORD;
  RegionSize : SIZE_T;
  State : DWORD;
  Protect : DWORD;
  Type_9 : DWORD;
end;
{$EXTERNALSYM _MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION}
TMemoryBasicInformation = _MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION = _MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
{$EXTERNALSYM MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION}
```

This only works when used in a 32-bit calling process, not when used in a 64-bit calling process.

Use `IsWow64Process()` to check whether `PIDHandle` is a handle to a 32-bit or 64-bit process, and then scan its memory using the appropriate record type, eg:

```pascal
// 32-bit and 64-bit processes can scan the full address space of a 32-bit process,
// but a 32-bit process cannot scan the full address space of a 64-bit process

type
  PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32 = ^MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32;
  MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32 = record
    BaseAddress: DWORD;
    AllocationBase: DWORD;
    AllocationProtect: DWORD;
    RegionSize: DWORD;
    State: DWORD;
    Protect: DWORD;
    _Type: DWORD;
  end;

  {$IFDEF WIN64}
  PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64 = ^MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64;
  {$ALIGN 16}
  MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64 = record
    BaseAddress: ULONGLONG;
    AllocationBase: ULONGLONG;
    AllocationProtect: DWORD;
    _alignment1: DWORD;
    RegionSize: ULONGLONG;
    State: DWORD;
    Protect: DWORD;
    _Type: DWORD;
    _alignment2: DWORD;
  end;
  {$ENDIF}

function VirtualQueryEx32(hProcess: THandle; lpAddress: Pointer; var lpBuffer: MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32; dwLength: SIZE_T): SIZE_T; stdcall; external 'kernel32' name 'VirtualQueryEx';

{$IFDEF WIN64}
function VirtualQueryEx64(hProcess: THandle; lpAddress: Pointer; var lpBuffer: MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64; dwLength: SIZE_T): SIZE_T; stdcall; external 'kernel32' name 'VirtualQueryEx';
{$ENDIF}

procedure TForm1.DoSomethingWithBuff(const ProcessName: string);
begin
  // do particular stuff with Buff
end;

procedure TForm1.ScanMemory32(PIDHandle: THandle; const ProcessName: string);
var
  MemStart: DWORD;
  ReceivedBytes: SIZE_T;
  MemInfo: MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32;
begin
  MemStart := 0;
  while (VirtualQueryEx32(PIDHandle, Pointer(MemStart), MemInfo, SizeOf(MemInfo)) <> 0) do
  begin
    if ((MemInfo.State = MEM_COMMIT) and (not (MemInfo.Protect = PAGE_GUARD)
    or (MemInfo.Protect = PAGE_NOACCESS)) and (MemInfo.Protect = PAGE_READWRITE)) then
    begin
      SetLength(Buff, MemInfo.RegionSize);
      if (ReadProcessMemory(PIDHandle, Pointer(MemInfo.BaseAddress), Buff,
          MemInfo.RegionSize, ReceivedBytes)) then
      begin
        DoSomethingWithBuff(ProcessName);
      end;
    end;
    Inc(MemStart, MemInfo.RegionSize);
  end; 
end;

{$IFDEF WIN64}
procedure TForm1.ScanMemory64(PIDHandle: THandle; const ProcessName: string);
var
  MemStart: ULONGLONG;
  ReceivedBytes: SIZE_T;
  MemInfo: MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64;
begin
  MemStart := 0;
  while (VirtualQueryEx64(PIDHandle, Pointer(MemStart), MemInfo, SizeOf(MemInfo)) <> 0) do
  begin
    if ((MemInfo.State = MEM_COMMIT) and (not (MemInfo.Protect = PAGE_GUARD)
    or (MemInfo.Protect = PAGE_NOACCESS)) and (MemInfo.Protect = PAGE_READWRITE)) then
    begin
      SetLength(Buff, MemInfo.RegionSize);
      if (ReadProcessMemory(PIDHandle, Pointer(MemInfo.BaseAddress), Buff,
          MemInfo.RegionSize, ReceivedBytes)) then
      begin
        DoSomethingWithBuff(ProcessName);
      end;
    end;
    Inc(MemStart, MemInfo.RegionSize);
  end; 
end;
{$ENDIF}

procedure TForm1.ScanMemory(PIDHandle: THandle; const ProcessName: string);
var
  Is32Bit: BOOL;
begin
  if not IsWow64Process(PIDHandle, @Is32Bit) then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  if Is32Bit then begin
    ScanMemory32(PIDHandle, ProcessName);
  end
  {$IFDEF WIN64}
  else begin
    ScanMemory64(PIDHandle, ProcessName);
  end
  {$ENDIF};
end;
```

Comment: Hummm that is really good... I'll accept as answer because makes very sense, but my problem, I was debugging and I note that in fact, the program didn't stop responding, it was just very slow while searching something inside the memory read as AnsiString... As I used the same code to parse the memory in x86 processes without any stress, I just changed from AnsiString to String the var type, and it got faster... And is working now, but I'll implement your solution too, because for me it still unclear why AnsiString was so slow...

Comment: `String` is an alias for `AnsiString` in Delphi 2007 and earlier, and for `UnicodeString` in Delphi 2009 and later. `AnsiString` and `UnicodeString` use the same memory manager.  `AnsiString` should not be behaving slower than `UnicodeString`, unless you are using slower code to scan through the `AnsiString` than the code you are using to scan through a `UnicodeString`.  You will have to profile your code to see where the extra time is actually being spent.